# How to use model data in template?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-model

I have created `FIXTURES` using `ember-model` and I am trying to access it on template, but it is not showing any result if I use `{{model.name}}`.  It is working fine with `each` helper.

I want to access single node of model like `{{model.name}}` without using any `each` helper.

My model code:

```
Astcart.Home.FIXTURES=[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "logo_url": "img/logo.jpg",
        "name": "gau",
        "list": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "amit"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "amit1"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

My router code :

```
  Astcart.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
      return Astcart.Home.find();
    }
  });
```

My template :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home"> 

    {{model.name}}

    <ul>
        {{#each item in model}}                                         
            <img  {{bindAttr src="item.logo_url"}}></img>               
            <li>{{item.name}}</li>
            {{#each item in item.list}} 
                <li>{{item.name}}</li>
            {{/each}}               
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

I have updated my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sachin1989/d5bWS/7/)

Comment: can you create a jsbin with just the part that is not working?

Comment: @intuitivepixel : I have updated my code at http://jsfiddle.net/sachin1989/d5bWS/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to change your template name to `index`, or your route to `Astcart.ApplicationRoute`, because the template name and route name must match.

The current configuration:

Route

```
Astcart.IndexRoute
```

Template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
```

don't work.

The `find()` without params, will perform a `find all data`, and this will always return an array.

If you want a single data, you can do one of the following choices:

1- Pass the id in the find method, but you need to know the id:

```
Astcart.Home.find(1);
```

This will return a single object, then you can use `{{model.name}}` or `{{name}}` (because the context of the template is the `model`), without the `each` view helper.

2- Get the first object of the array:

```
{{#with model.firstObject as item}}
    <img  {{bindAttr src="item.logo_url"}}></img>               
    {{item.name}}
{{/with}}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Rodrigues Correa : But how to work with object which contains both array and single value?

Comment: Hmm array and single at same time? I don't know what is your goal, but I think that would be better by example something like: you have a model `User` and it belongsTo `UserProfile` (instead of Home), so when you sign in in the app, you will have a signed user, and your profile. So instead of Home.find(user_id), you will do: `model.userProfile.logo_url` etc.